# Atribuir período do dia para horas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tenho o seguinte df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'hora completa':['21:35:00', '22:16:00', '00:50:00', '09:30:00', '14:30:00']})
print(df)
```

```
  hora completa
0      21:35:00
1      22:16:00
2      00:50:00
3      09:30:00
4      14:30:00
```

Preciso criar uma coluna 'período' com os critérios:

```
- Madrugada: Entre 00:00 e 05:59
- Manhã: Entre às 06:00 e 11:59
- Tarde: Entre o 12:00 e 17:59
- Noite: Entre às 18:00 e 23:59
```

Tentei resolver usando numpy, assim:

```
mask1 = df['hora completa'].between('06:00:00', '11:59:00')
mask2 = df['hora completa'].between('12:00:00', '17:59:00')
mask3 = df['hora completa'].between('18:00:00', '23:59:00')
mask4 = df['hora completa'].between('00:00:00', '05:59:00')

df['periodo'] = np.where(mask1, 'Manhã', 
                         mask2, 'Tarde', 
                         mask3, 'Noite', 
                         mask4, 'Madrugada')

print (df)
```

Mas dá o erro abaixo:

> ```
> TypeError: where() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)
> ```

O que estou errando? É possível fazer um `def` com `if` e `else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem que a função `where` recebe no máximo 3 argumentos, e você esta informando 8! Você pode utilizar a função [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply) e informar como parâmetros, uma função a qual será executada para cada item e o `axis`:

```python
import pandas as pd

def periodo(linha):
  horario = linha['hora completa']
  if '06:00:00' < horario < '11:59:00': return 'Manha'
  elif '12:00:00' < horario < '17:59:00': return 'Tarde'
  elif '18:00:00' < horario < '23:59:00': return 'Noite'
  elif '00:00:00' < horario < '05:59:00': return 'Madrugada'
  return ''

df = pd.DataFrame({'hora completa':['21:35:00', '22:16:00', '00:50:00', '09:30:00', '14:30:00']})
df['periodo'] = df.apply(periodo, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Saída:

```
  hora completa    periodo
0      21:35:00      Noite
1      22:16:00      Noite
2      00:50:00  Madrugada
3      09:30:00      Manha
4      14:30:00      Tarde
```

[Veja funcionando em repl.it](https://repl.it/@wellmotta/306912-stackoverflow) e também [criei um Gist no GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/wellmotta/48563e91087bd4be4bf0ed1115bdffeb)

#### Referência

- [pandas.DataFrame.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply)

Comment: Obrigado NoobSaibot, dessa forma funcionou bem mas só quando crio um df com pd.DataFrame (igual criei aqui como exemplo). Mas quando fui utilizar no dataframe original que tenho não funcionou. Deu o seguinte erro: TypeError: ("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.time'", 'occurred at index 0'). O tipo das células é o mesmo (non-null object) para o df original e para o df criado com pd.dataframe. Tentei mudar algumas coisas, criei um outro df a partir da coluna de horário e o mesmo erro. O que pode ser? Obrigado.

Comment: @RicardoStorck esse exemplo de DataFrame que colocou é baseado no DataFrame que você tem ?

Comment: Sim meu caro, baseado nele. É a mesma coluna chamada hora completa. O df original tem mais de 98 mil linhas e 16 colunas. Quando tentei aplicar o código imaginei que fosse problema com o tipo das células. Mas é o mesmo em ambos.

Comment: Veja: https://repl.it/repls/AmusingMasculineMolecule

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado. Também consegui de outra forma. Assim:
periodo = []
for row in df['hora completa']:
    if row >=0 and row <=5:
        periodo.append('Madrugada')
    elif row >=6 and row <=11:
        periodo.append('Manhã')
    elif row >= 12 and row <=17:
        periodo.append('Tarde')
    elif row >= 18 and row <=23:
        periodo.append('Noite')

df['periodo'] = periodo